# how to implement a partial view with generic type inference

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, generics

I am working through [this](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/implement-efficient-data-paging) sample and came across a problem. To implement pagination, the sample extends list and adds pagination to it. This list is then used as the model.

In my view I want to add a pagination control. In the sample they simply add it to the page but I want to make it a user control because I plan to implement pagination in multiple pages. Off course This has to be a strongly typed view but since I can't use wildcards in C# I can not implement it like this:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<PaginatedList<?>>" %>
```

Since I only plan to use the members declared in `PaginatedList` and not in `List` I don't need the type.

In a C# method we could solve this problem with type inference but how is it don in a partial view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define an interface containing the pagination properties that you want to use in your partial view.  Have your `PaginatedList<T>` class implement this interface.  Have your partial view be typed to the interface.

```
public interface IPaginated
{
    int PageIndex  { get; }
    int PageSize   { get; }
    int TotalCount { get; }
    int TotalPages { get; }
}

public class PaginatedList<T> : List<T>, IPaginated
{
   ... should not need to change ...
}

<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<IPaginated>" %>
```